# Change position of Billing address in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent, billing-address

**I want to change default billing address position which is coming under the payment information, I need it before shipping address(same as magento 1).**

Anyone have any idea to achieve it, Please help?

Comment: Need to write own customization. We are also doing the same.

Comment: There is no easy solution to achieve it. You will have to write a custom extension that customize checkout steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reorder (switch) billing address before shipping address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167526/how-to-reorder-switch-billing-address-before-shipping-address)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167526/how-to-reorder-switch-billing-address-before-shipping-address check this

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: billing-address-form in LayoutProcessorPlugin.php:20 when using extension given on above thread.

Comment: Fixed above problem by Change the setting from Payment Method to Payment Page under Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Checkout Options->Display Billing Address On

Answer (score 1):

We need to modify `applyBillingAddress` function in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js` around line 231:

And comment out this part:

```
/*                if (shippingAddress &&
                    shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
                    (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
                ) {
                    selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
                }  
*/
And commend out code around line 34:

/*
           if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
               selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
           }  
*/
```

But we can't modify the core javascript files itself (Magento 2 best practices!).

Instead we will create a simple Magento 2 module and will create a file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` with the following content:

```
var config = {
map: {
'*': {
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver':
     'Vendor_Module/js/checkout-data-resolver'
,'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default':
     'Vendor_Module/js/shipping-save-processor/default'
 }
}};
```

Then copy `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-data-resolver.js` and comment out in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-data-resolver.js around line 231:`

applyBillingAddress: function () {
    var shippingAddress;

```
if (quote.billingAddress()) {
    selectBillingAddress(quote.billingAddress());

    return;
}  
shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

/*if (shippingAddress &&
    shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
    (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
) {
    selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
}*/
```

And copy `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js` and in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js comment out code around line 34:`

```
'use strict';

return {
    saveShippingInformation: function () {
        var payload;

        /*if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
            selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
        }*/

        payload = {
            addressInformation: {
                shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
```

After that delete `pub/static/frontend` folder regenerate your static content:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear magento cache and you should be all set.