# how to reorder (switch) billing address before shipping address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

on the onepage checkout I need to reorder the billing address before the shipping address.
in fact the logic should be the other way around than it is now.
if the shipping address differs from the billing address you should be able to edit it.
now you can edit the billing address if it differs from the shipping address.
also the billing address should appear on the same "page" as the shipping address. currently step 1 in the magento checkout steps.

how would I do this? maybe there is a plugin for this but I couldn't find one yet.

I attached a screenshot of a german shop doing it like this:

[image]

I found the .html template file for the billing form and it seems this is the place where it ends up in the checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Payment</item>
            </item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- ... -->
                <!-- merge your payment methods here -->
                <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- merge additional data after payment methods here -->

<!-- I think here the billing form ends up -->

                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

But it's not specifically placed here and I can't seem to find another place where it is injected to that place.

Comment: The billing address form is added in the file `Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php`.

Comment: Yep that's it. There I managed to reorder at least. Still have to switch the address logic though.

Comment: you have using custom checkout?

Comment: Need to override `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` & change position as I am thinking. Not sure

Comment: https://inviqa.com/blog/technical-guide-magento-2-checkout. Try to change `sortOrder` of `<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">` & `<item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">`

Comment: Hi @DarsVaeda Please check above

Comment: @AnkitShah That won't work as I just need to move the billing address not the whole billing step. Also as Aaron pointed out the first step to do it is write a module that overwrites LayoutProcessor. I already did that successfully but still the logic of choosing the billing address being the same as the shipping address is not correct. And additionally I'm not sure if the whole process will work. At least I can go on in the checkout but I'm not sure about side-effects so far.

Comment: The suggested solution seems to work, but filling-in billing address information is optional - pressing Next button proceeds, although nothing was entered in the billing address. "My billing and shipping address are the same" is not ticked. How to make entry of billing address on the page to be required ? Don't have the required level yet to comment under the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Aaron pointed out the form is added in `Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php`.
With this information I developed a module with an after plugin that hooks onto that processor:

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\ReorderBillingForm\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    )
    {
        // get billing address form at billing step
        $billingAddressForm = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'];

        // move address form to shipping step
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billing-address-form'] = $billingAddressForm;

        // remove form from billing step
        unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']);

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="<vendor>_<module>" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="reorder-billing-form"
                type="<vendor>\<module>\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="<yourOrder>"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '<vendor>_<module>',
    __DIR__
);
```

This successfully reorders the billing address form (and hopefully saves some headaches for other people). But there is still work needed on the javascript(?) that handles the `billing address is the same as shipping address` mechanism. As this still works the "standard" way.

Additional info:

I saw that in the backend if you create a new order the layout is exactly as wanted. The billing form is "before" the shipping form and the logic is the other way around too.
If I can find the time I think it might be beneficial to look at the code there. Maybe it is possible to use it in frontend too.

Comment: Shouldn't the namespace be namespace `<vendor>\ReorderBillingForm\Block\Checkout;` ?

Comment: Not sure. I ran into caching problems (yet again) it seems. Sometimes it wouldn't work, sometimes it did.
I rewrote the module and now it works all the time.
It was important to use `aroundProcess`. I updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer but i get the following error `Notice: Undefined index: billing-address-form` `in LayoutProcessorPlugin.php:20`

Comment: Hmm strange, I don't get that. But you can check how the $jsLayout is structured by debugging.
I don't have a running instance currently. If I setup another one I'll try to find out what might be the issue.

Comment: Did you already update the answer? you are still using afterProcess, not around Process  @DarsVaeda We are using your solution but have the Billign Address on the Payment Step still appearing

Comment: Just checked again, it works with afterProcess. I think my comment might be a typo.

Comment: Ah and btw. the namespace in my answer works.

Comment: Have you tested this with virtual orders? I suspect the above code will return an undefined index error, but I didn't test.

Comment: No, it's hardly tested at all. It's merely a starting point. As said you still have to work on all the knockout hoopla too.

Comment: @darsVaeda: I have done same like what are you doing same thing but checkout step is blank nothing is showing can you help me out

Comment: hi , i am getting error Notice: Undefined index: billing-address-form in LayoutProcessorPlugin.php please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: hm, intresting. The billing address form appears before shipping address, but not removed from the 2nd step. unset is done, dont understand why is it appears?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Undefined index: billing-address-form` in `LayoutProcessorPlugin.php` occurs when you have the checkout property **"Display Billing Address On**" set to "**Payment Method**" instead of "**Payment Page**".

Fix with:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET VALUE = 1 WHERE path = 'checkout/options/display_billing_address_on';
```

I would have preferred to add this as a comment to DarsVaedas post (see above), but I don't seem to have the permission …

Comment: thanks @jaybong for adding the sql statement to fix this!