# Magento2 - Reposition billing address form to customer-email region

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, jslayout

I'm trying to reposition the `billing-address-form` below the `authentication` form. But I can't figure it out.

Preferred result:
[image]

**What I have done so far**

I have found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170732/46214) question, and made a module for it.

## <vendor>/<module>/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Checkout\Block\Checkout; //<-- I think the first Checkout needs to be removed.

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as LayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $layoutProcessor, callable $proceed): float
    {
        $jsLayout = $proceed();

        // get billing address form at billing step
        $billingAddressForm = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'];

        // move address form to shipping step
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billing-address-form'] = $billingAddressForm;

        // remove form from billing step
        unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']);

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

## <vendor>/<module>/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" type="<vendor>\<module>\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" />
</config>
```

But after the compilation I get the following error on the checkout page:

> Cannot declare class <vendor>\<module>\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin, because the name is already in use in /app/code/<vendor>/<module>/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like you've literally used "`<vendor>`" and "`<module>`" in your namespace and as directory names. These are meant as parameters, placeholders to be filled with your own values. For example "`Frank\Checkout`" instead of "`<vendor>\<module>`". The same applies for the directory names.

Second, there is a configuration setting that's used to point where the billing address form is rendered at the path `checkout/options/display_billing_address_on`. It can be found in the admin Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options:
Set `Display Billing Address On Display Billing Address On` to `Payment Page`.

This will normally render billing address *below* the payment-method selection, but the Plugin you've made for the LayoutProcessor will removed it from *below* the payment-method selection and add it on the shipping step.

Note: I don't think you'd want it to be moved to the shipping step, because you're selling virtual products - they don't get shipped so the shipping step is not shown on the checkout. You may way to move it somewhere else by changing the `afterProcess` method in the plugin to:

```
public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
{
    // get billing address form at billing step
    $billingAddressForm = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'];

    // move address form to before the payment methods
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'] = $billingAddressForm;

    // remove form from billing step
    unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']);

    return $jsLayout;
}
```